# How to prevent form submission with enter key when a server action is pending?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I've been toying around with the NextJS starter example mentioned in [this course](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/) and I was wondering what would be the proper way to prevent users from submitting a form by pressing the enter key when the server action is running/pending.
There are [examples in NextJS's docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/data-fetching/server-actions-and-mutations#pending-states) of using the useFormStatus hook to disable the submit button, but the form still can be submitted with the enter key, duplicating the request to the server/db.

I know this seems like a very basic interaction, but I haven't been able to find much information about it. What would be the best practice here? Wrapping the server action with a useTransition hook? Debouncing the action?

Thank you in advance!

The sample form is very simple, it just takes three values and inserts them in the db.

```
export default function Page() {
  async function createInvoice(formData: FormData) {
    'use server'
 
    const rawFormData = {
      customerId: formData.get('customerId'),
      amount: formData.get('amount'),
      status: formData.get('status'),
    }
 
    // mutate data
    // revalidate cache
  }
 
  return
    <form action={createInvoice}>
      ...
      <SubmitButton /> // uses useFormStatus to disable the button while the action is pending
    </form>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your form has multiple input elements, the best way to disable submit on pressing the enter key is by using `e.preventDefault()` for `onSubmit`.

```html
<form onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
```

```js
submitHandler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I would like to let the user submit by hitting the enter key and *only* prevent them from doing it when the server action is running/the form is already being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the form status and the `onSubmit` prop of the form to prevent a new submission if it already submitting.

```
import { useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'

export default function Page() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()

  async function createInvoice(formData: FormData) {
    'use server'

    const rawFormData = {
      customerId: formData.get('customerId'),
      amount: formData.get('amount'),
      status: formData.get('status'),
    }

    // mutate data
    // revalidate cache
  }

  return
    <form onSubmit={pending ? (event) => { event.preventDefault(); } : undefined} action={createInvoice}>
      ...
      <SubmitButton /> // uses useFormStatus to disable the button while the action is pending
    </form>
}
```

Comment: That would be a nice solution but I'm afraid that useFormStatus doesnt work at the form level [link](https://es.react.dev/reference/react-dom/hooks/useFormStatus#useformstatus-will-not-return-status-information-for-a-form-rendered-in-the-same-component)
But based on that idea I figured out another solution, lifting the 'pending' state up from the button component with a useEffect hook:
`
useEffect(() => {
    onSubmit(pending);
  }, [onSubmit, pending]);
`
This way I can access and store the 'pending' value in the form component's state, but it doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Comment: I see, yeah that makes sense. It seems one way or another you will need some React state to track when the form should be blocked from submission. Where that state lives, whether passed between components or stored in a React Context, is the more subjective decision I imagine.